# Using VB in excel. How do I return the highest value Regex match from multiple matches?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

[Found this vb regex code online which returns the first regex match.](http://pastebin.com/Qxc6BXby)

I changed .global = true. Now how do I get the function to return the highest value numeric match and not the first match?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the highest value numeric match you will have to loop through the collection of matches found as suggested by Issun. Try this

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strgToTest As String
    Dim hVal As Long

    strgToTest = "1 2 3 44 55 66 77 a b c 5 6 88"

    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "\b[0-9]+\b"
    re.Global = True

    Set Matches = re.Execute(strgToTest)

    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Match In Matches
            If Val(Match.Value) > hVal Then hVal = Val(Match.Value)
        Next
        MsgBox hVal
    Else
        MsgBox "No Match Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by highest value, but if you are getting back numeric values, just create a 'max' variable and loop through the matches, checking the previous with the new to find out which is larger (the old fashion way of getting MAX from a list of values).

Comment: There are those that make is slower and more complicated (like create an array and run worksheetfunction.max on it) :p

Comment: Yes but I call that over engineering :P